# PHP мусор из временных файлов php*.tmp в рабочей директории

Tags: php

наблюдаю раз в 2-3 месяца в рабочей директории мусор из PHP*.tmp файлов, которые непонятно откуда появляются. Сервер под WindowsServer2012 PHP+Apache+mySQL.

В чем причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно, что это файлы с временными, необходимыми для работы данными. По одной только конфигурации сервера ничего не сказать - нужно посмотреть на содержимое файлов и на конфигурационные файлы приложений. Скорее всего, максимум что можно будет сделать - вынести эти файлы в отдельную дирректорию. Больше сказать будет сложно.

Comment: Странно что они вообще появляются, есть еще один сервер с один-в-один конфигурацией PHP - там такого не было никогда.)) Это просто сюрприз.

Comment: @yavafree Значит не один-в-один

Comment: Установил sys_temp_dir - не помогает. Вообще непонятно откуда ноги растут.

Comment: По содержанию файла стало понятно, что это сторонняя библиотека старая испоьлзовала базовую директорию для временных файлов и потом их стирала, но при сбросе соединения файлы оставались!)